# Trouble Adding ANTLR to Classpath in Java: "package org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree does not exist"

Tags: environment-variables, classpath, antlr, antlr4

I'm having difficulties adding ANTLR to my Java classpath and getting it to work. I've followed the usual steps, but I'm still encountering the error message:

```
package org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree does not  exist(compiler.err.doesnt.exist) org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree
```

I've downloaded the ANTLR JAR file (antlr4-4.7.1-complete.jar & antlr-4.13.1-complete.jar) from the official website. (for some reason i downloaded 2)

Here's what I've tried so far;

I've set my classpath using the following command in my terminal:

```
export CLASSPATH="/Users/ciansullivan/Downloads/antlr4-4.7.1-complete.jar"
```

I've also added a directory containing the JAR file to my PATH.

(I can confirm that when I echo the CLASSPATH, it returns the correct path to the file.)

However, I'm still getting the error. I suspect that the issue might be related to having multiple versions of ANTLR, as I have two installed on my system. I've tried adding each version separately to the classpath, but the problem persists.

Could someone please guide me on how to correctly set up ANTLR in my Java project and resolve this error? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Additional Information:

Operating System: [Mac OS]

```
ANTLR Version(s): [antlr4-4.7.1-complete.jar & antlr-4.13.1-complete.jar]
```

IDE: [VS Code]

Comment: I don't see a "antlr4-4.7.1-complete.jar" in the [download directory](https://github.com/antlr/website-antlr4/tree/gh-pages/download). If anything, it's "antlr-4.7.1-complete.jar". The compiler can't find the runtime in the jar cause the classpath is to a non-existent file. Anyway, please use the current version, 4.13.1 only, and especially don't reference both jars on a classpath.

Comment: I have switched to use the 4.13.1 like you suggested, and also removed the other off of my computer. However I still get error.

This is my classpath now: CLASSPATH=/Users/ciansullivan/Documents/DCU-Coursework/CA4003/Antlr/lib/antlr-4.13.1-complete.jar

For some reason this is the only antlr related command i have been able to run:
"java org.antlr.v4.Tool", even though the package "org.antlr.v4.Tool" seems not to exist when i look at it in VSCode at the referenced library. But there is one for "org.antlr.v4.tool", even though this does not seem to work. (only difference being "T" vs "t")

Comment: `org.antlr.v4.tool` is a package (e.g., [here](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/d25d421780286e3de0714831a5f82eca59234249/tool/src/org/antlr/v4/tool/ANTLRMessage.java#L7)). `org.antlr.v4.Tool` is a class. You cannot run `java org.antlr.v4.tool` because it is a package. You should be on java version >= 11. Try `ls -l /Users/ciansullivan/Documents/DCU-Coursework/CA4003/Antlr/lib/antlr-4.13.1-complete.jar` to verify the file exists, then `javac -cp '/Users/ciansullivan/Documents/DCU-Coursework/CA4003/Antlr/lib/antlr-4.13.1-complete.jar:.' *.java`.

Comment: ciansullivan@Cians-Air lib % ls -l /Users/ciansullivan/Documents/DCU-Coursework/CA4003/Antlr/lib/antlr-4.13.1-complete.jar
-rw-r--r--@ 1 ciansullivan  staff  2139203 Oct 16 16:37 /Users/ciansullivan/Documents/DCU-Coursework/CA4003/Antlr/lib/antlr-4.13.1-complete.jar
ciansullivan@Cians-Air lib % javac -cp '/Users/ciansullivan/Documents/DCU-Coursework/CA4003/Antlr/lib/antlr-4.13.1-complete.jar:.' *.java
zsh: no matches found: *.java

----

From what I understand here, my file exists but when i run your command it says: "no matches found: *.java"

Comment: You are supposed to "cd" to the directory containing your .java source files.

Comment: i am in the directory containing my .java files, when i try to compile i still get the error antlr is not found

Answer (score 0):

Stick the following in a shell script:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh

ANTLR_JAR="antlr-4.13.1-complete.jar"

if [ ! -f "$ANTLR_JAR" ]
then
    # Download the ANTLR jar if it isn't in the current working directory
    wget "https://www.antlr.org/download/$ANTLR_JAR"
fi

# Create a test grammar
cat << EOF > Test.g4
grammar Test;
parse : ANY* EOF;
ANY : .;
EOF

# Generate the lexer and parser classes
java -jar "$ANTLR_JAR" Test.g4

# Create a driver class
cat << EOF > Main.java
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTree;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String source = "test";
        TestLexer lexer = new TestLexer(CharStreams.fromString(source));
        TestParser parser = new TestParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
        ParseTree root = parser.parse();
        System.out.println(root.toStringTree(parser));
    }
}
EOF

# Compile all java source files
javac -cp "$ANTLR_JAR" *.java

# Run the Main class
java -cp .:"$ANTLR_JAR" Main
```

and run it. It will print:

```
(parse t e s t <EOF>)
```